# Convert Double to CLLocationDegrees [SWIFT]

Tags: ios, swift, core-location, cllocationmanager, cllocationcoordinate2d

I'm trying to convert two arrays into CLLocationDegrees, and from there merge them together into one array (`CLLocationCoordinate2D`).

So let's start from the beginning:

I've two arrays of the type Double that I received from Firestore. (One with latitudes, and one with longitudes). I'm trying to convert these arrays into CLLocationDegrees and than merge them together to one array which should be of type `CLLocationCoordiante2D`.

In the top of the code (in the class) I've this:

```
var latitude:[Double] = []
var longitude:[Double] = []

var locations: [CLLocationCoordinate2D] = []
```

And after the viewDidLoad I've created a function which looks like this:

```
func insertInMap()
{
    if (CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled())
    {
        //WARNING BELOW
        locations = [CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude as! CLLocationDegrees, longitude: longitude as! CLLocationDegrees)] 
        print(locations) 

        //Insert the coordinates (In the correct order) into mapView.            
        //Draw a polyline between the coordinates
    } else{
        //Code here
    }
}
```

The warning I get is:

> Cast from '[Double]' to unrelated type 'CLLocationDegrees' (aka 'Double') always fails

If I print "locations" it returns:

> [0, 0]

Anyone know how to solve this issue? Please let me know.
And if you're here to dislike, atleast write the reason for it in the comments.

Comment: you are adding the array in coordinates not a single element

Comment: Your `latitude` and `longitude` variables are defined as arrays, the constructor of CLLocationCoordinate2D require Double and not array of Doubles

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik Yeah, but I've them in an array (Since there is a lot of latitudes and longitudes in it) So do you know how I can solve this?

Comment: @arturdev Do you know how I can fix it using my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read the warning carefully.

Both `latitude` and `longitude` are arrays, and the `CLLocationCoordinate2D` `init` method expects **one** `latitude` and **one** `longitude`.

You could use `zip` and `map` to create the coordinate array

```
assert(latitude.count == longitude.count, "Both arrays must contain the same number of items")
locations = zip(latitude, longitude).map{CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: $0.0, longitude: $0.1)}
```

or even shorter

```
locations = zip(latitude, longitude).map(CLLocationCoordinate2D.init)
```

The assert line causes a fatal error if the condition fails.

Comment: The arrays always contains the same number of items.
I added ur code and removed my "location = blabla" but still returns [0, 0]

Hmm

Comment: The code is supposed to work. The print statement should display something like `[__C.CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 1.0, longitude: 4.0), __C.CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 2.0, longitude: 5.0), __C.CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 3.0, longitude: 6.0)]`

Comment: I used the code, but still docent really work as expected :/ returns [0, 0]

Comment: Ohhhhhh, I'm so stupid. I didn't called my function lol. But I've no idea where the print [0, 0] comes from. I'll try it out hold on